# Добавление класса к элементу, выбранному по id

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Почему не добавляется класс к элементу, выбранному по `id`, по клику на `#check`?

```js
$("#check").click(function() {
  var cur = $("#wrappername");
  cur.addClass("wrapperdiv");
});
```

```css
#wrapperdiv {
  height: 50px;
  width: 607px;
  background: #808080;
}
```

```html
<div id="#wrappername" class="lol">
  <input type="text" id="namecheck" name="name" placeholder="Имя" />
  <p id="check">Сохранить</p>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что `id` вашего элемента не `wrappername`, `#wrappername`. Выбрать элемент с таким `id` можно таким образом:

```
$("[id='#wrappername']");
```

А можно `id` элемента сменить на `wrappername`:

```
<div id="wrappername" class="lol">
```

Пример с `#wrappername`:

```js
$("#check").on("click", function() {
    $("[id='#wrappername']").addClass("wrapperdiv");
});
```

```css
.wrapperdiv {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="#wrappername" class="lol">
  <input type="text" id="namecheck" name="name" placeholder="Имя" />
  <p id="check">Сохранить</p>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Так как вы добавляете элементу класс, а не `id`, то и стили должны быть привязаны к классу (`.wrapperdiv { ... }`).